# Permutations on words

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

> How many six-letter words can be formed by using the letters of the word ‘PRESSES’?

So my doubt comes to which proceedure is valid to solve this problem:

- The book solution is:
  We omit in turn each of the four letters ‘P’, ‘R’, ‘E’ and ‘S’.
  This leaves six letters which we must then arrange in order.
  1 If an S is omitted, there are then 2 Es and 2 Ss,
  so number of words = 6!,
  2! × 2! = 180
  2 If an E is omitted, there are then 3 Ss,
  so number of words = 6!,
  3! = 120.
  3 If P or R is omitted (2 cases), there are then 2 Es and 3 Ss,
  so number of words = 6!,
  3! × 2!
  × 2
  = 120
  Hence the total number of words is $180 + 120 + 120 = 420$
- While my logic works like $\frac{7P6}{3!\cdot2}$ , 7Permute6 because it involves permuting 7 letters into 6 spaces and there are 3 letters repeated (the S's) and 2 letters repeated (the E's). And this gives you 420 too.

Is my logic/approach valid? Or is it just a coincidence that both methods get to the same answer, but mine is ilogical?

Comment: The basic issue with your approach is that you do not know how many repeated letters would be there In every selection of 5 letters out of 6

Comment: typo, it should've been 7Permute6, now it's edited

Comment: My point still stays the same

Comment: okay, so dividing the cases is the only way?

Comment: That’s correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic gives the correct answer only because exactly one letter is omitted. The result is the same as the number of seven-letter words, $\frac{7!}{3!2!}$. There is a bijection between six- and seven-letter words: PRESSE <=> PRESSES